# Browsing "Senders" in Finder also returns code that doesn't contain the message I'm searching for in Pharo?

Tags: compilation, smalltalk, pharo

Opened a fresh Pharo 5 image, opened Finder and searched for the + selector. Then selected the + and clicked Senders. Got about 5000 results, most of them seem fine, however upon closer inspection some results seem to missing any reference of my message send.

Not a few I might add, about 1700 of them seem to be erroneous and contain no reference of + what so ever. What do you think is the problem? Here's one example:

[image: Example]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Update

The search goes both through the textual source code and the bytecode; so it shows you the method, because it found `#+` in the bytecode, but the browser is too limited to show you both text and bytes, so it shows you only the text (even though the match was done on bytecode)

As for bytecode itself, Pharo (re)compiles a method every time you save it; so for example when you save the following method

```
Something>>loop
    1 to: 10 do: [ :each | ]
```

the system will compile it, and when you inspect the method and look at the bytecode, you will see this

[image]

You can write the bytecode by hand too I believe.

---

### Original answer

Because for some special selectors it also looks through the bytecode, which you can see when you inspect the method itself.

[image]

This can be very easily discovered in less than a minute by looking through the code of Pharo itself (once you are more comfortable with Pharo):

- `#+ senders` gives you the list of senders of a selector,
- so you look at the implementation of `senders` and go through the available call chain (you can select selector with mouse or doubleclick and ctrl+n to show you the senders browser)

  - `senders` → `allSendersOf:` → `thoroughWhichSelectorsReferTo:`
- and there you see

.

```
thoroughWhichSelectorsReferTo: literal
    "Answer a set of selectors whose methods access the argument as a 
    literal. Dives into the compact literal notation, making it slow but 
    thorough "
    | selectors special byte |
    "for speed we check the special selectors here once per class"
    special := Smalltalk
        hasSpecialSelector: literal
        ifTrueSetByte: [ :value | byte := value ].
    selectors := OrderedCollection new.
    self selectorsAndMethodsDo: [ :sel :method |
            ((method refersToLiteral: literal) or: [special and: [method scanFor: byte]]) ifTrue: [selectors add: sel]].
    ^ selectors
```

Comment: Your answer is informative but I still don't get it. Seeing the code in the picture I uploaded I don't see any call to + or #+. By what mechanism does a call to + get into the byte code when I don't actually write it. Does just compiling do this?

Comment: Looking at BytecodeEncoder>>#if:isSpecialLiteralForPush: essentially looking where exactly does the system decide to include this send:+ bytecode?

Comment: @Niki The compiler does a lot of optimizations, you can also sometimes see `<primitive>` pragmas in methods (use Finder and select 'Pragmas' search), which also triggers the VM to behave differently

Comment: I understand now. There is something behind the scenes doing this, probably for performance reasons. I think I found where this happens #genSendSpecial:numArgs: in Encoder. It's doing some "asserting" and at the end it is "stream nextPut: specialSelectorIndex + 175", I don't get how this is generating a send: + what's the logic behind it?

Comment: @Niki see `OCASTTranslator>>emitToDo:step:` ; the compiler performs semantic analysis and converts the `to:do:` call into specific bytecode. You can also perform the compilation by hand (`Someclass compile: 'myCode`) and trace the execution with debugger.

Comment: @Niki if you want deeper explanation, the better place to ask is mailing list.

Comment: Perfect! OCASTTranslator>>emitToDo:step: is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 4):

Just to clarify @Peter's answer a little bit:

The iteration

```
  1 to: 10 do: [:each | dictionary at: each put: each]
```

sends `+ 1` to the block variable `each` every time it iterates the block.

We do not see `+ 1` in the source code, but it actually happens *behind the scenes*. The reason why such a hidden send is found is that Smalltalk does not analyze the source code but the `CompiledMethod` and does that by looking at the literal frame and, as Peter says, also at the bytecodes.

For instance, by compiling and inspecting the method

```
m
  1 to: 10 do: [:i | i foo]
```

we can see that the intermediate representation Ir tab reads:

```
 1. label: 1
 2. pushLiteral: 1
 3. popIntoTemp: #i
 4. goto: 2

 5. label: 2
 6. pushTemp: #i
 7. pushLiteral: 10
 8. send: #'<='
 9. if: false goto: 4 else: 3

10. label: 3
11. pushTemp: #i
12. send: #foo
13. popTop
14. pushTemp: #i
15. pushLiteral: 1
16. send: #+                       "Here we sum 1 to i"
17. popIntoTemp: #i
18. goto: 2

19. label: 4
20. returnReceiver
```

Lines 15 and 16 represent the `+ 1` that actually takes place. Note that the symbol `#+` is not in the literal frame (Raw tab of the inspector). It is not in the AST either because `+` is absent from the source code

---

**Why this happens?**

There are some special messages, `#to:do:` being one of them, that get *inlined* when your code sends them. Inlining a method means including its bytecodes in the sender rather than actually sending them.

For example, if your code reads

```
self foo.
1 to: 10 do: [:i | i foo].
self bar
```

your method has 4 sends: `foo`, `to:do:`, `foo` (again) and `bar`. However, the compiler will produce only 3 sends `foo`, `foo` and `bar` and will include the bytecodes of `to:do:` in place.

And given that `to:do:` needs to sum `1` to the block argument `i`, the `send +`, which is actually sent, is detected as occurring in your method (because it fact, it does).

However, if you rewrite the method as

```
m
  | block |
  block := [:i | i foo].
  self foo.
  1 to: 10 do: block
  self bar
```

the compiler will refuse to inline `to:do:` and will send it as a regular message. As a result your method will not be a sender of `+` any longer.

---

**If to:do: is not sent, why my method is a sender of it?**

This is a subtler question. As we have seen, when `to:do:` is inlined, it is not sent. How then it is possible that my method is recognized as a sender of `to:do:`?

Well, the reason is that the compiler will anyway add the symbol `#to:do:` to the literal frame of your method. And it will do that just for allowing your method to be found as a sender of `to:do:`. It doesn't matter whether your method actually sends `to:do:` or not, the inlining technique is just an optimization. At a higher level of abstraction we all want to see that our method is a "sender" of `to:do:`, hence the "trick" of adding it to the literal frame.

Comment: I understand now why it is found and displayed as a result, basically there is a + in the byte code, but finder can't see byte code so you see the text which doesn't actually contain +. Where does smalltalk decide to do this kind of _behind_ adding o messages, how does it work?

Comment: Perfect! I get it now!